# What to use for Android Icon indicators

Tags: android, eclipse, button, icons, wifi

I'm trying to make Icon indicators if Wifi is ON or OFF and the same for GSM but I don't know what's the best Form Widget to use ? toggle button,image view,image button ?? taking into consideration I want to apply conditions like if Wifi is connected display this image if it's not display the second image.So, I hope if you have an example or anything that would be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
    if(isWifiConnected())
    {
         your_imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_wifiON);
    } 
    else 
    {
        your_imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_wifiOFF);
    }
```